The fundamental group of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}_2$
Let $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ be the group of reall $2\times 2$ matrices with unit determinant. The center of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ consists of the identity matrix and its opposite which is denoted by $\mathbb{Z}_2$. How can I prove that $\pi_1 (SL(2,\mathbb{R})/\mathbb{Z}_2)\cong \mathbb{Z}$?

Hint: study the/a maximal compact subgroup of $PSL(2,R)$.

@MoisheKohan Thank you. Could you please give me a reference for the definition of maximal compact subgroup and $PSL(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Any textbook on Lie groups will contain a proof of the fact that every Lie group with finitely many connected components is homotopy-equivalent to its maximal compact subgroup. As for $SL(2,R)$ and $PSL(2,R)$, it is a very good exercise in linear algebra or hyperbolic geometry.

@MoisheKohan I got it well. I really appreciate your help.
